# Where are incoming messages queued/stored when sendmail is communicating with a milter?

Tags: sendmail

CentOS 5.x | SendMail

I'd like to better understand how milter hand-offs work.

When a remote MTA initiates an SMTP session, my understanding is that Sendmail hands the message data off to the milter during that session. Where/how is this message data stored?  Is this all done in memory? Or is there a "queue" area where message data for milter is stored for pickup by the milter?

If it helps, let's say I'm calling a milter like this:

```
INPUT_MAIL_FILTER(`foo', `S=unix:/var/lib/foo/foo.sock, F=T, T=C:5m;S:3m;R:5m;E:5m')dnl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the milter and what purpose it serves. For example [MIMEDefang](http://www.mimedefang.org) uses its own spool area in order to perform checks on the message body. Other milters do not maintain their own spool / queue and rely on [the milter architecture](https://www.milter.org/developers/design) and whatever sendmail hands them from its queue.